# Golang custom handler for server

Tags: http, go

I want to use a custom method on `http.ListenAndServe`

Here is what I have

```
http.ListenAndServe(":8000", ErrorHandler)

func ErrorHandler(h http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        h.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    })
}
```

Error

```
cannot use ErrorHandler (type func(http.Handler) http.Handler) as type http.Handler in argument to http.ListenAndServe:
        func(http.Handler) http.Handler does not implement http.Handler (missing ServeHTTP method)
```

How can I add a custom method to `ListenAndServe`?

Comment: Your `ErrorHandler` is not an `http.Handler` it is a function that retuns a handler, and takes one as argument, that you can then pass to `ListenAndServe`. So this compiles `http.ListenAndServe(":8000", ErrorHandler(nil))`. Presumably you pass an actual handler value instead of `nil` to the `ErrorHandler` call or else `h.ServeHTTP` will eventually panic

Comment: I see, I guess I need to think this over then:)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `ErrorHandler(h http.Handler) http.Handler` func is basically just "middleware" and not a real handler. It takes a handler `h` and returns a new handler. [http.StripPrefix](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/f1e880386b668a26dd6b7afdea43c9041a917fa5/src/net/http/server.go#L1965-L1986) is an example of such "middleware".

If you don't want middleware, but just a handler then you need to define your function a little differently:

```
func ErrorHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    // do stuff with r and w
}
```

Now you can pass your `ErrorHandler` to `ListenAndServe` although you still need to cast it to the proper `http.Handler` type like so:

```
http.ListenAndServe(":8000", http.HandlerFunc(ErrorHandler))
```

[http.HandlerFunc](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#HandlerFunc) is an adapter that turns a function, if it has the right signature, into an `http.Handler`.

Finally, if you don't like the casting, you'll need to define a type instead of a just a function and you'll need to define a method on that type that is required for it to satisfy the `http.Handler` interface type.

```
type ErrorHandler struct{}

func (h *ErrorHandler) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    // do stuff with r and w
}

http.ListenAndServe(":8080", &ErrorHandler{})
```

Read more about it here https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Handler

Comment: thanks. that looks promising. I just gave it a quick shot and will look at this in depth later on. As far as I could see, this will handle all requests, not just the error one, correct?

Comment: Well since you're passing it to `ListenAndServe` that is correct. What you usually want to do is to instantiate a [mux](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ServeMux) register your handlers by path patterns and then pass the mux to `ListenAndServe`.

Comment: @xhallix quick example of what that would look like https://play.golang.org/p/htxoXo7f8U

Comment: thank you, your help did the trick

https://github.com/xhallix/go-router/blob/master/router.go#L22